# How can I use it with the regionmatches loop in java

Tags: java

I want to use the regionmatches command with a loop. I need to use regionmatches and true / false for the two string entered, but I don't know how to use regionmatches and for loop together.

Like this but I need to use regionmatches instead of split.

```
    boolean varmi;
    varmi = false;
    String aranan  = "Furkan";
    String str = "Merhaba Benim Adım Furkan";
    String[] bol = str.split(" ");
    for (String kelime : bol) {
        if(kelime.equals(aranan)) {
            varmi = true;
        }
        }
    System.out.println(varmi);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would use this method according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int)).

It takes 4 arguments which are the following

```
toffset – the starting offset of the subregion in this string.
other – the string argument.
ooffset – the starting offset of the subregion in the string argument.
len – the number of characters to compare.
```

```java
boolean varmi = false;
String aranan = "Furkan";
String str = "Merhaba Benim Adım Furkan";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.regionMatches(i, aranan, 0, aranan.length())) {
        System.out.println("Found at index " + i);
        varmi = true;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(varmi);
```

This prints

```
Found at index 19
true
```

Comment: That's what i need. Thanks for help :)